# How to download an email attachment asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, web, webforms

I upload a file which has .msg extension to a folder, then i want to download the file to another path with a button click on my web page.

What is the way of download .msg files to a folder at asp.net?

I have tried this

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + attachmentName);
 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFolder/") + attachmentName);
 Response.End();
```

But it returns "Thread was being aborted" error.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Methods
Response.ContentType
Response.AddHeader
Response.TransmitFile
```

should get it done.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile?view=netframework-4.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried Response.TransmitFile but I couldn't handle it, i edited my question about it

Comment: Resonse.end does that, just wrap it in a try catch and it should work.

Comment: Response.ContentType = ContentType;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
Response.WriteFile(fullUploadPathwithFileName);
Response.End();

Comment: I tried wrap it in a try catch but i think i couldn't use it right way, i put my download code in try block and catch block is empty, and still download doesn't work. What is the right way use it in a try catch for avoid that error? Thank you for answers